# How to track down segmentation fault in Linux?

Tags: segmentation-fault

My server went down suddenly and the ISP supports says it may have had a segmentation fault. I am wondering how to track down and possibly fix this so it will not occur again?

Thanks

Comment: It "may have had" ? So they don't actually know?

Comment: @gparent actually no. That's the only explanation that I've got.

Comment: Is that a shared or dedicated host, vserver or physical/vm?

Comment: It's a dedicated server

Comment: Not enough information has been provided here for us to help you.  There are so many different reasons for a segmentation fault, and to fix it you'd have to be ready to edit the source code after analyzing the core dump and make the change and make a new binary.

Comment: When you say "my server", do you mean a process running on a machine? Or a machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such segfaults are usually logged in the system's syslog facility. The exact name of which changes by distro, though `dmesg` should have it if it's recent enough; it'll be in `/var/log` one way or the other, though.

Interpreting the message will be another story entirely. But at least you'll know what faulted.